# Drupal Gallery Formatter and Colorbox

Tags: jquery, drupal, formatting, gallery, colorbox

Can anyone tell me how to make [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) open a Colorbox modal when the slide is clicked? I have both modules installed as well as CCK, etc... Also, I have made sure that the colorbox library is properly installed, too! I know it is probably something simple, but it has eluded me up to this point! I am using the Drupal Colorbox module. Thank you in advance! 
BTW - I LOVE stackoverflow.com! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just got it working. I had another javascript file running that was breaking the colorbox script. I hope this helps someone! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi Ron,

I have the above mentioned modules installed too but my images do not appear in a colorbox when clicked. What kind of javascript did you have running? I don't think I got anything else going really but it still doesn't seem to work for me. Any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you!